# "looks like we are having some server troubles" Dreamweaver phonegap build

Tags: cordova, dreamweaver

I am working on a project with dreamweaver CS 6, using the phonegap build panel.

The build service says that there is no project settings file and I have the choice of "Create as a new project". When I do this and press continue, the build service works in the background for a while and then alerts "Looks like we are having some server trouble".

I have been having this problem since I installed DW CS 6, but have managed to make it work on one occasion. I can't see what was different from then and now.

My project is not over the 10 mb size limit (it's 7mb).

The init_status.txt log file contains the following:

```
{"message": "Failed to upload application. Unable to create zip file. Reason: null","error": 404}
```

But I don't know what to make of it, or if it is even relevant to my problems.

It seems that others have been having the same problems, and that this may be linked to an unresolved issue. But as I said, I have been able to make it work in the past.

Any pointers in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the problem as well. If you login to your account at build.phonegap.com and only have 1 project in the apps section, go to that apps settings and take the check mark out of the "only approved collaborators (listed below) can download this app". Then rebuild your app from dreamweaver and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Same here. I had to go to the actual PhoneGap build website (https://build.phonegap.com) and set up my first app manually.

After entering my first set of (BlackBerry) keys and a zipped project file, I was able to generate an app across the platforms - and I was also able to select the project from inside Dreamweaver. Now I can access the DW PhoneGap Build Service menu just like [the video](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/digital-design-cs6/using-the-phonegap-build-panel-in-dreamweaver-cs6-to-build-native-applications-for-android-and-ios-devices/) shows.

Can't rebuild the project though - different error message:

```
Error finding app information. The connection may have been lost
```

Seems like Adobe has a bit of troubleshooting to do ;)